# How to convert a List[String] or List[Double] to List[Row]?

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, row

How do I convert a `List[Double]` or `List[String]` to `List[Row]` in Scala? Row is `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`.

Let's say that I have a `List(1,2,3)`:

```
val list = List(1,2,3)

// Now, list is a List[Int]
```

I want to convert this list to `List[Row]`.

Answer (score 4):

To create a `List[Row]` with a single element in each row, you can do the following:

```
list.map(x => Row.fromSeq(Seq(x)))
```

This will first make each element in the list into a `Seq` with that single element. Then `Row.fromSeq()` is used to create a `Row`.

Comment: yeah it works @Shaido